# Changing times on a page based on a users timezone

Tags: javascript, html, localization

I am writing a static content web page for an international group I am in. There are weekly phone-in meetings and I would like to list the times localized either to the user's location, system time, or even based on a user selecting their time zone. I was thinking of using toLocaleString() but I'm not sure how to pass it a day of the week and a time and have it convert it to a localized view. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I should have specified to begin with, I'd like the dates to be formatted like "Tuesday's at 05:30". I'm flexible with the exact formatting but I need to only show the day of the week (which will change with the time zone) and the time of day (HH:MM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *JavaScript* the default human readable output of [***Date***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype#Methods) is the computer's local time. You only have the choice between local time methods and specially named UTC methods unless you write a custom ones.

Notice how the following reflects my timezone

```
(new Date()).toString(); // "Sun Jun 28 2015 16:54:16 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)"
```

So what you need to do is use an international time which is then displayed for all your users, which is either the *Integer* representation of the time (*ms* since the *unix epoch*) or the time in some known offset (i.e. use UTC)

```
+new Date(); // 1435506856000 (ms since midnight of 1st Jan 1970 UTC)
(new Date()).toISOString(); // "2015-06-28T15:54:16.000Z" (ISO 8601 date time code)
```

The integer will have the best backwards compatibility.

Then in your page you would build a *Date* from this value,

```
new Date(1435506856000); // "Sun Jun 28 2015 16:54:16 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)" or equivalent in your local timezone
```

If you're not using the *Integer* or an *ISO 8601* compliant string you may need to use [`new Date(Date.UTC(yyyy, mm, dd, hh, etc...))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) rather than simply `new Date` so it will be interpreted properly

---

In short, store and send dates and times in *UTC / ISO 8601 / ms since unix epoch* and the native *Date* will handle the localisation for you

---

> "Tuesday's at 05:30"

The method you are looking for is [`d.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

```
function formatDate(d) {
    var day = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];
    function pad(x) {
        if (x < 10) return '0' + x;
        return '' + x;
    }
    return day[d.getDay()] + "'s at " + pad(d.getHours()) + ':' + pad(d.getMinutes());
}

formatDate(new Date); // "Sunday's at 18:28"
```

Also, are you sure you want possessive `Tuesday's` and not plural `Tuesdays`? If you're contracting *is* consider writing it in full instead.

Comment: EDIT I should have specified to begin with, I'd like the dates to be formatted like "Tuesday's at 05:30". I'm flexible with the exact formatting but I need to only show the day of the week (which will change with the time zone) and the time of day (HH:MM).

Comment: @YehudaMiller The method you're looking for is [`dateInstance.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) which will give an integer from `0` (_Sunday_) to `6` (_Saturday_) calculated using the client's local time. You can then convert this to the name of the day using an _Array_ `['Sunday', 'Monday', ..., 'Saturday']`. The issue here would become the language rather than which day.